# Revision help URL contains wrong header

Tags: bug, status-completed

There are two revision urls listed on the help page but they both seem to contain the same detailed information. The header for the non-guid version contains the url for the one that takes a guid. Should these be consolidated into one or the two help pages be changed to reflect their differences?

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=revisions/{id}
vs 
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=revisions/{id}/{revisionguid}

Answer (score 2):

Headers have been fixed.